# Best Way To Place Media Queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

What is the best way to place media queries in HTML?

1. In same CSS file like:

   ```
   .my-text {
     font-size: 30px;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
      .my-text {
        font-size: 24px;
       }
   }

   .my-img {
     width: 100%;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
      .my-img {
        width: 80%;
       }
   }

   {more styles...}

   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
      {more styles...}
   }
   ```
2. Or in same CSS but like:

   ```
   .my-text {
     font-size: 30px;
   }

   .my-img {
     width: 100%;
   }

   {more code....}

   @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
      .my-text {
        font-size: 24px;
       }

      .my-img {
        width: 80%;
       }

       {more code...}
   }
   ```
3. Or should I use different stylesheets in HTML head tag using media query like:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="small.css">
   ```

I'm learning web designing but I'm a bit confused which will work fine..

Comment: Definitely, I will advise you to use second or third way. It depends only on your habits. But I think the third option is the clearest.

Comment: I think this question is opinion based and thus [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Just to weigh in, I'd be angry if I had to work on a project 'the third way.' After trying it, you'll soon find out that you need to see the progression of a responsive layout - all in one place. This is totally opinion based - so you aren't going to get an answer, but I would imagine that most people use SCSS or Stylus in 2017 - and they use a combination of 1 and 2. https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/50fe2e2fd5c0dda47007431dec2ca2e3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortest answer is: it depends what you're trying to achieve.

The first option is the worst in terms of file size and readability because of doubling every `@media` rule makes all the rules longer and hard to effectively debug.

The second option (one CSS file with all media-specific rules grouped under one `@media` block per media type) is the best when there are rules which overlaps each other in terms of adding something to values coming from the other `@media` block. In this case this would be more SEO-friendly and economical (by means of number of requests) than downloading several separate CSS files to any matched `@media`.

The third option is the most effective when `@media` classifiers don't overlap with each other at all (because it results in a smaller file to download per page load, and only one CSS file is loaded at a time. This would be the best way to go if you have some CSS files for different layouts per device, while only one is needed per device resolution - i.e. one for horizontal resolutions below 320, one for 320-720, one for 720 upwards and one specifically for printing.

Answer (score 3):

The 2nd option would be the best practice as I have seen good designers use the 2nd strategy to implement media queries.
First, write all your styles, then at the end, use media queries on whatever element needed.